# Django/Postgres - column does not exist error after I made a right mess of the database

Tags: django, postgresql

After a string of silly errors which invovled me directly importing data into a PostgreS DB then deleting the database after it caused duplicate key issues, I get an error (full traceback below) on makemigrations/migrate/runserver.

I shifted back to SQLite and it works fine, however I need to get this running in PG.  I have restored the database so the table structure is correct, however, I still get the same error so I'm presuming (guessing) there is some cached sql code on the Django/Python side that is causing this to fail.

Note that lead_auditor_id is not referenced anywhere in my project, although there is a lead_auditor table which has the default id column.

Any clues would be very welcome after a lot of hours spent searching and trying various solutions.

```
$ py manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column actionlog_action.lead_auditor_id does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."action", "actionlog_action"."action_owner_id", "actionlog...
                                                         ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Jon\django_projects\effortlessactiontracker\effortlessactiontracker\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path('actionlog/', include('actionlog.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Jon\django_projects\effortlessactiontracker\actionlog\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\Jon\django_projects\effortlessactiontracker\actionlog\views.py", line 99, in <module>
    class OverdueActionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
  File "C:\Users\Jon\django_projects\effortlessactiontracker\actionlog\views.py", line 102, in OverdueActionListView
    num_actions_overdue = len(list(filter(lambda action: action.overdue, Action.objects.all())))
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1151, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column actionlog_action.lead_auditor_id does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."action", "actionlog_action"."action_owner_id", "actionlog...
```

Answer (score 0):

- Solution is that..
- Create that column manually OR Rollback your migration files

Comment: this is a really bad answer, please write things like this as a comment. If you really try to help a beginner, try to elaborate a little more and explain what and how and where and so on.

Comment: Dear @hansTheFranz. He already messed with model migration. I also get this kind of issue. But at the end I fix that by Manually DB query or Rollback the migration file :). If you have solution then please commit it.

Comment: Thanks Ashish, it did set me on the right path - confused myself going in circles and using the same field name in multiple models.  I just needed to read the traceback more carefully.  Still not sure why I was unable to recreate the table structure using makemigrations (I did try rolling back).  Still plenty to learn...